# I'm getting the message 'ancestor C:\Users\max\gradle is not a directory' in command prompt

Tags: gradle, command, prompt

I typed `gradle init --type basic` into the command prompt and I got a:

```
'Failure...
C:\Users\max\gradle is not a directory.'
```

I already added gradle to the path and when I typed gradle I got a successful build.

Does anyone know why I am getting this response?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, you are trying to run Gradle in the same directory, where it was installed. This command tries to create a default directory structure for base project, but it can't, since you already have a file named `gradle` in this dir.

Just try to run it in some empty folder, where your project will be located